# Why would BigQuery suddenly throw data format error

Tags: sql, firebase, google-bigquery

The following query has suddenly stopped working:

```
SELECT
  CAST((SELECT up.value.string_value FROM UNNEST(user_properties) up WHERE key = "user_id") AS INT64) AS user_id,
  (TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(CAST(event_timestamp/1000 AS INT64))) AS event_date
`firebase.dataset.events_*`
```

The error is as follows:

```
bad int64 value:
```

The query has been working fine for months and something happened today to cause this error. Did anyone have the same issue? Is it likely the issue is in our data? Could it be a temporary issue on the GCP side? Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like an overflow problem to me, are you sure that event_timestamp/1000 still fits in an int64?

Comment: I found what the issue was. The user_id field is a string, and some events (for reasons unknown) contain an empty string, which cannot be cast to an integer. I think the solution would be to 1) fix the bug sending empty strings on our apps and 2) safe cast ignoring the empty strings / ignore the lines with an if statement.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

use safe_cast() instead cast

```
SELECT
  safe_cast((SELECT up.value.string_value FROM UNNEST(user_properties) up WHERE key = "user_id") AS INT64) AS user_id,
  (TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(CAST(event_timestamp/1000 AS INT64))) AS event_date
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but does anyone know how safe_cast avoids the error?

Comment: @Sandun `SAFE_CAST` returns `NULL`